# How to get InnoDB table names that are linked to foreign key value?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have multiple tables (Eg : A,B,C....etc with Foreign Key ADDRESS_ID) linked to 'address' table where ADDRESS_ID is the primary key. Tables A,B,C... may have address_ID value or not. Is there a query that I could get table names with given ADDRESS_ID in address table ? Note that this is not table names for a given column in 'address' table. I need table names for a given **Address_ID value** in address table if it is already referenced in other tables. (I do not know all tables that may have address_id referenced.)

```
Address table 
ADDRESS_ID (PK) |   STREET ADDRESS_1   |   STREET_ADDRESS_2  |   CITY  |  ZIPCODE    


Table A
A_ID  |  ADDRESS_ID (FK) |  FIELD _1  |   FIELD_2

Table B
B_ID  |  ADDRESS_ID (FK)|  FIELD _!  |  FIELD_2

Table C
B_ID  |  ADDRESS_ID (FK) |  FIELD _! |  FIELD_2
```

more tables ......

This is what I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE 
information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND
TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'flower_db' AND
TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME = 'address';
```

But this does not support what I exactly wanted.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added example table structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'address'
```

(adjust the query as needed)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 'TableA' as Table_Has_Address       
 FROM TableA
 GROUP BY ADDRESS_ID
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_ID = @address_id THEN 1 END) > 0

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 'TableB' as Table_Has_Address       
 FROM TableB
 GROUP BY ADDRESS_ID
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_ID = @address_id THEN 1 END) > 0

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 'TableC' as Table_Has_Address       
 FROM TableC
 GROUP BY ADDRESS_ID
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_ID = @address_id THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Yes, I know this method but as I said, I do not know how many tables are there referencing ADDRESS_ID in address tables. In that case this method does not work and highly inefficient if I have to write this for each table.